# Proving the existence of a linear transformation based on a given kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb{V} = \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{R^2}, \ker\phi = \{[x,y]^T \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$.

Does there exist a linear transformation $\phi: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{W} $?

I understand that the transformation turns a unit circle to a null space, but lack knowledge how to move from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint,

If there exists a linear transformation $\phi$ then $ (0,0)\in \ker(\phi)$.

Comment: Is it correct that $[0, 0] \in ker \phi$, but $0^2 + 0^2 \neq 1$ which leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @Avgustine If the vector space $ \mathbb{R^2}$ defined by usual addition then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of a linear map is a linear vector subspace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2074494)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My point though was the kernel of a linear map is a linear vector space which a circle is not.